# JavaScript Github Action: Writing to $GITHUB_OUTPUT without set-output and without @actions/core

Tags: javascript, github-actions

For this question, there are a few constraints:

- This needs to work without any NPM packages, including @actions/core. Hence I can't do `core.setOutput(name, value);`
- It used to be possible to `` console.log(`::set-output name=${key}::${value}`); ``. This method is deprecated as [announced on this blog post](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/).

The recommended new way according to the blog is to write to the new $GITHUB_OUTPUT environment file. Unfortunately there is no JavaScript example on the blog post.

The simple implementation would be to run:

```js
fs.writeFileSync(process.env.GITHUB_OUTPUT, `${key}=${value}`);
```

Is there a simpler, nicer or recommended way to implement this in JavaScript?

I tried to `` console.log(`::set-output name=${key}::${value}`); ``. This method is deprecated as announced on this blog post.

Comment: Did you try the implementation suggested [here](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/issues/1218)? It seems a bit different than the one you shared.