# At GitHub Actions when I am run JavaScript, how can I create environment? (GITHUB_ENV or GITHUB_OUTPUT)

Tags: javascript, github, variables, github-actions, octokit

Does anyone have an idea how I can create an environment variable under GitHub Actions when I run a JavaScript file? I would like to use this environment variable during a next step, in the case of a job. If it can already be used in another step, it is not difficult to transfer it to another job.

I couldn't find any solution on the Internet, only the deprecated console.log solution... Can anyone help me please? I also use octokit, but I don't understand the difference between create environment variable and create repository variable. I understand the repository variable because I can see that at my repository and I created that from my other script. But I don't see how to set the environment option anywhere under the repository. Could anyone please possibly help?

My current object is:

Make an variable at GitHub Actions workflow run at JavaScript. So at the next step I can use it.

I tried this solution: [JavaScript Github Action: Writing to $GITHUB_OUTPUT without set-output and without @actions/core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74473991)

Tried:

```js
console.log(echo "TEST=VALUE")
console.log(`TEST=${myValue}`)
```

Comment: Did you try `setOutput` (see the [docs for @actions/core](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/tree/main/packages/core#inputsoutputs))?

Comment: And for environment variables, [`exportVariable`](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/tree/main/packages/core#exporting-variables).

Comment: @BenjaminW. I am very glad that someone replied so quickly! It means a lot to me! I forgot that the `setOutput` didn't work for me at all, but the `exportVariable` command it worked fine as it should! Interestingly, I could not get the value to print out during the same step using `echo ${{ env.TEST }}`, but during the next step, it appended it under env! Do you know if it might append it to the other steps? Also, can it only be used for one step within a job, or can it be used globally as a variable everywhere after the-after-next-step?

Comment: How does `setOutput` not work for you? How do you reference it in the next step? As for availability of environment variables: they're not available in the current step, but in all subsequent steps of the same workflow ([docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It worked with both, I just used the `setOutput` command incorrectly! Sorry for the late reply! Thanks again for your help!